# Historic TeX Live distributions: HTTPS/SFTP mirror

Tags: texlive

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX document as part of a Travis CI job. I need to use the 2017 version of TeX Live until a 2018 [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/raabf/latex-versions/) for the Docker container I am using is released.

The suggestions online are to use `ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/` for the package repository which fails, because FTP does not work well with Travis CI's NAT implementation.

Are there any repository mirrors for historical versions of TeX Live that are available *without* using a file transfer protocol from the 1970s? Perhaps also with some integrity assurances? SFTP, HTTPS?

The standard CTAN mirrors don't include historical releases, as far as I can tell.

Comment: there are 2018 builds in the link you gave?

Comment: Yes but they're not stable (see `latest` tag)

Comment: Given that the underlying binaries are stable (texlive doesn't change binaries mid year) I'd have thought they would be stable enough but perhaps your policy prevents use of such an image. I can't help otherwise (we run texlive 2018 on travis simply by installing it from ctan's tlnet copy,  not via docker)

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see where I get with it, there's no real harm trying. It's a shame there's no way to get at the old releases though!

Comment: Not sure if it is any help to your usage but there is http:// ftp @  http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2017/ and packages at http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final/archive/

Comment: >Not sure if it is any help to your usage< 


It totally is - this works fine because it's exposed w/ HTTP which works fine with Travis, please post as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main historic repository for TeX Live is maintained at Utah and currently has 23 years of historic versions from 1996  up to current 2019

Try not to overload it with requests, If you are able to find a more local Ctan repository then avoid constantly relying on this one basket.

To be able to use another protocol instead of plain ftp there is also http:// ftp @

http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/

More recently individual packages can also be searched and found so in this case of looking for tlnet final we see

http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final/archive/