# A similar concept to Python's virtual environments in Latex?

Tags: xetex, packages, miktex

I am looking for similar concept to Python's virtual environment in Latex, that is, is there a way to save all the latex packages that I am using "in their current version" and list them in some sort of a requirement .txt file so that other users could install the same packages (same versions) and run my latex source code.
The motivation is to make sure that no conflicts between packages could arise in the future (if a package is updated).

Comment: there are some examples on site eg using the --recorder option then zipping up all files used, but to be honest it's almost never needed do this, you'd expect a 20 year old document to work using _current_ packages, it is less likely to work using 20 year old packages from the time unless you are archiving the entire format and fonts and extended engine such as xetex

Comment: Visual or virtual?

Comment: There are yearly historical versions of TeX Live available that contain the versions of the engines/compilers and the versions of the packages at that particular year, including installation scripts (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460132/historic-tex-live-distributions-https-sftp-mirror). So if your document works with, e.g., TeX Live 2019 then you can tell other users to install TL2019 from that archive. But while there are occasionally breaking changes and new bugs in packages usually a document is easy to fix so always using the latest version is generally a good idea.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/bundle-packages-with-a-document